# How far do entity beans within entity beans go?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.0

I'm not sure if I'm asking this correctly but I'll try to make it as clear as I can. I have an entity bean that has foreign keys to other entity beans. One of these foreign keys brings back a set of the other entity beans. Then I want to get another entity bean out of each entity bean in the set. So it's like this

`Bean 1 -> Bean 2 -> Bean 3`

or

`Bean 1` gets `Bean 2` gets `Bean 3`

I have a HQL query bringing back a collection of `Bean 1`. I know I can get at `Bean 2` from `Bean 1` but am I able to get at `Bean 3` from `Bean 2` by only running the original query? Or will I need to run a separate HQL query to get at `Bean 3`?

Comment: The whole point of an ORM framework is to remove the need for you to manage the Object graph. You should be able to access the `Bean 3` starting at `Bean 1`. Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can bring the entire tree back in HQL if you need to.  [See this reference for information](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins)

> A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects using a single select. This is particularly useful in the case of a collection. It effectively overrides the outer join and lazy declarations of the mapping file for associations and collections. See Section 19.1, “Fetching strategies” for more information.

```
from Cat as cat
    inner join fetch cat.mate
    left join fetch cat.kittens
```

Comment: Even if you don't `JOIN FETCH`, the ORM framework will use separate queries if it needs to to retrieve your object tree/graph.

Comment: I thought the point of his question is "but am I able to get at Bean 3 from Bean 2 by only running the original query?"  I think he wants to avoid separate lazy fetches using HQL

Comment: I just want OP to know that if you had `A` has `B` has `C`, doing HQL `FROM A a`, you can then do `a.getB().getC()` and depending on Session boundaries and eager/lazy fetching, you wouldn't have to do any other HQL yourself.